# Como obtengo el numero de vocales de un input en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener las vocales de un input, pero este solo me da de salida el numero de letras que hay en total, no de vocales.

```
function contarVocales() {
var texto = document.getElementById("textov").value;
  var tamtexto = texto.length;
  var vocales = "aeiou";
  var contador = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < tamtexto; i++) {
    if (vocales.indexOf(tamtexto[i]) !== 0) {
      contador++;
    } else {
      alert("No hay vocales");
    }
  }
  alert(contador);
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia de la subcadena o -1 si no se encontró nada. Te devuelve el número total de caracteres porque estás comparando `indexOf` con 0 y como no se encuentra, se añade 1 al contador.

Answer (score 1):

Casi lo tienes hecho.

`indexOf` devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia de la subcadena o -1 si no se encontró nada. Te devuelve el número total de caracteres porque estás comparando `indexOf` con 0 y como no se encuentra, se añade 1 al contador. Además en el código estás intentando buscar la letra en `tamtexto` que es un número (o `undefined`), por lo que nunca se va a encontrar entre las vocales.

La solución entonces es en dos pasos:

- Asegurarte que buscas la letra (en `texto`)
- Comparar `indexOf` con -1.

Aquí el código con esos cambios (además moví la alerta de no vocales al final para que no saltará en cada pasada del bucle):

```js
function contarVocales() {
var texto = document.getElementById("textov").value;
  var tamtexto = texto.length;
  var vocales = "aeiou";
  var contador = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < tamtexto; i++) {
    // estabas comparando tamtexto en lugar de texto
    // indexOf devuelve -1 si no se encuentra
    if (vocales.indexOf(texto[i]) > -1) {
      contador++;
    }
  }
 
  // mover el error de no hay vocales al final
  if (contador > 0) {
    alert(contador); 
  } else {
    alert("No hay vocales");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="textov" />
<button onclick="contarVocales()">Calcular</button>
```